# Is the unconditional mean of error terms not equal to 0?

Tags: regression

[image]

I’m a little unclear on why this proof constantly utilises mean of u(which should be just 0).
Can someone please clarify if I’m missing something?

Comment: I suppose the distinction has to be made between the expected value of the errors, which, under suitable assumptions will indeed by zero, and the arithmetic mean of the errors for a sample of finite size $n$, which will generally not be zero (we do not know if it is as we do not observe the errors).

Comment: Where is there any use of an assumed mean of the $u_i$?